# Como parar o rotativo do bootstrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou querendo colocar um fim no carousel do bootstrap, por exemplo quando ele chegar na última imagem do efeito carousel o usuário não pode mais ir para próxima imagem somente voltar.

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar a opção `wrap` a `false`:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({wrap: false});
```

Podes ver aqui a funcionar:

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({wrap: false});
```

```css
html, 
body, 
.carousel, 
.carousel-inner, 
.carousel-inner 

.item {
    height: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
    background: #74C390;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
    background: #51BCE8;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
    background: #E46653;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```